# Finding superscripts in string as string is read in from file

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to take text from a table in a word document into excel. I need to remove superscripts from the text I read in. Its simple to remove superscripts from an excel document but I need to remove the superscript characters as they are written to the excel documents. The reason for this is that the word document contains lots of strings which are the same but superscript numbers or the trademark symbol have been added at random so my spreadsheet wont recognise these strings as being the same.

My code is quite long but the relevant bit is here

```
Dim myDoc As Word.Document
Dim i As Integer 
Dim iTable        As Integer  'table number index
Dim iRow          As Long     'row index in Excel
Dim iCol          As Integer  'column index in Excel
Dim j as integer, i as integer, c as integer

With myDoc.Tables(1) ‘the table I want to read in strings from
    j=3
         For iRow = 1 To .Rows.Count
               Cells(i, j) = WorksheetFunction.Clean(.Cell(iRow, 1).Range.Text)  ‘i is set elsewhere in code
               For c = 1 To Len(Cells(i, j))
                    If Cells(i, j).Characters(c, 1).Font.Superscript = True Then
                    MsgBox “superscript found”
                    End If
                Next c
               j = j + 1
          Next iRow
End With
```

However this doesn't work, as it never alerts me to any superscripts (I can work on deleting them later at the moment I just want to make sure it finds them). If I change it so that it alerts me when a character is found which isn't a superscript then it works fine. It's odd because when I check what it wrote to my spreadsheet, a lot of the characters are superscript so they are there.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Cheers

Comment: Have you tried manually stepping through that code? Does the relevant `If` get executed? Are the correct cells referenced? All your calls to `Cells.` are not fully qualified - they always implicitly point to `ActiveWorkbook.Cells.`. Is that what you intend the code to do?

Comment: If I re-run the code but get it to alert me when a character is not superscript then it does that, so the If is being executed.  By Cells I mean Activeworkbook.Cells, would it be safer to explicitly say that?

Comment: I wouldn't call it safer, but it most definitely expresses your *intent* better. Regarding your issue: Set a breakpoint at the line of your `If` expression and have a look at the value of `Cells(i, j).Characters(c, 1).Font.Superscript` in the Immediate window when the loop is in a cell that has superscript. What does it tell you? It seems to me that everything *should* work.

Comment: Also, instead of always doing `ActiveWorkbook.Cells` you could once assign `Set Ws = ActiveWorkbook` at the start and then only refer to `Ws.Cells`. This makes life easier if you need to adapt this code to work on a different workbook or if you at some point want to extract that piece of code into its own `Sub`.

Comment: I've discovered a couple of things which shed a bit of light on it. I got the macro to display every character it read in and show the character along with the value of .font.superscript, and the superscript digits in the word document aren't coming out as superscript, and in fact they aren't written into my spreadsheet as superscript like I thought they were. The other superscript text it isn't finding is the trademark symbol which I'm guessing isn't just a superscript T and M but a special symbol? What could be causing it to not recognise the superscript digits? Thanks for your help so far!

Comment: @J.Booth: hmmm, is it possible that the table being copied from MSWord is being copied as an HTML Table instead of a Word table?

Comment: How can I tell? Earlier in the code I have the line Set myDoc = wdApp.Documents.Open(Filename:=myPath & myFile, ReadOnly:=True)

Comment: @J.Booth The trademark symbol ™ indeed is a symbol on its own, but can be used in super-/subscript as well. Try `chr(153)`.

Comment: Regarding the loss of information when transferring the text: You're operating on `myDoc.Tables(1).Cell(iRow, 1).Range.Text` which is equivalent to a string variable. Super- and subscript is metadata (infomation on the string's typesetting) and not contained within the pure text. Thus when you assign the `.Text` value to `Cells(i, j)` (which implicitly refers to `Cells(i, j).Value`) you lose that metadata. In effect, your worksheet never knows about any superscripted strings.

Comment: @ Inarion thanks a lot I think I'm going to try and paste it across instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is fine for finding superscripts in Excel cells. This means, if there are any superscripted characters in range, it will find them.

The problem is in this single line: 
`Cells(i, j) = WorksheetFunction.Clean(.Cell(iRow, 1).Range.Text)` where the full reference is `myDoc.Tables(1).Cell(iRow, 1).Range.Text` with `myDoc` being a Word document.
By referring to a Range's `.Text` property, you can only get a `String` value in return. This type cannot ever carry over metadata like super-/subscript, font size, etc. So, in effect, that information is lost in the process *and never reaches your Excel worksheet*! (Which is why you're unable to find it.)

Unfortunately I don't know the Word object model, so I can't tell how to transfer this metadata as well. Hopefully, someone with experience in this regard can chime in on that.

Alternatively, have a look at [some search results on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=copy+formatted+text+from+word+to+excel). Maybe there's something in there that helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I think I'll copy and paste it across instead.

Comment: @J.Booth Yeah, that seems to be working, from a quick glance at other questions. Good luck! :) (And if you feel I sufficiently answered your question, I'd appreciate if you accepted my answer. Or you can tell me in what regard you find it lacking, as well. Thanks!)